# Next.js 13 with react-transition-group. Can I use it for transition animations that take different paths?

Tags: next.js13, react-transition-group

First, because I am Korean, I spoke English incorrectly and used a translator. So it can be difficult to read. I apologize in advance

I was looking for an example of whether page transition animation is possible even when moving to a different route using react-transition-group in Next.js 13.

However, I only found examples of React, not Next.js.

When I move from /home to /detail, is it possible to make an animation in which the components of /detail appear after the animation of the components of /home disappearing using react-transition-group in Next.js?